# Reading environment variables from a foreign process

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables

I have a windows service which periodically checks a number of other processes and reports information on them back to a central location.

I'd like to extract any environment variables that those processes may be using. I'm currently doing this using some DllImport statements (e.g. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/143/entry-2686-working-with-environment-variables-in-c%23/), which works well for the most part.

This only seems to work, however, if the windows service and the process its analyzing are both being run by the same user. If the windows service runs as 'user1' and the process as 'user2', its environment variables cannot be inspected.

Is anyone aware of a cleaner way to fetch these environment variables (without changing the underlying applications), or a suitable workaround?

Comment: I kinda hope you cannot do that, as it seems pretty malicious. However, you could fall back to your first method using WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() maybe ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w070t6ka.aspx