# Extracting Environment Variables from a Foreign Process

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, environment-variables, windows-server-2003

I posted a question similar to this a few months ago ([Reading environment variables from a foreign process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047772/reading-environment-variables-from-a-foreign-process)), but had a follow up. Apologies if this isn't the correct etiquette.

I run a windows service that periodically scans processes for their environment variables. The service runs as  and only scans processes that also run as . This works fine.

If I were to run the service as 'Local System Account' (an admin on the machine), would it have the same capabilities, or would it not have permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Local System Account* is the most powerful user on the system, even more powerful than administrator accounts. So, whilst I have never attempted what you describe, I would expect that *Local System Account* would have sufficient rights.

Comment: In particular, the token for the local system account includes the local Administrators group.